# How to send a variable from express to pug?

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I want to send a variable from Express to Pug.

Therefore I found already that I have to use res.render(), but if I try this, I only get an undefined variable.

In my index.js:

```
app.post("/example", upload.single("photo"), (req, res) => { 
  {... some code}
  var html = "some text";
  res.render("results", {
    html: html
  });
```

and in my results.pug I try to show the text as a string:

```
p "#{html}"
```

At the moment I only get two "" on my page. 
But I need to show the result

Thank you for your help!!!! :)

Comment: Did you set the rendering-engine (correctly)? Something like `app.set('view engine', 'pug')`

Comment: I already send some information to pug with the following: `const resultsTemplate = pug.compileFile("public/results.pug")` and send some information: `res.send(resultsTemplate({
        image: base64String
      }))` but this didn't work with the variable...

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with how you are calling the variable in your pug template.  This is the easiest way to do it:

```
p= html
```

or

```
p
  div= html
```

If you really wanted to use [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) the syntax would be:

```
p #{html}
```

I'd bet that if you View Source on your current page you will have something that looks like this:

```
<p>#{html}</p>
```